# I can't find a layout file in settings page of Umbraco version8 but it can normal display in website

Tags: umbraco

I have trouble when I deal with a case that made by former colleague.
He made a `home.cshtml` and layout just only write one line:

```
@{ Layout = "master.cshtml"; }
```

I click any tree list in settings page but still can't find any file named master.cshtml!
But header is normal display of the webpage.
I really really so confused...

I check the file in visual code, I really sure the `master.cshtml` is header of `home.cshtml`, but in the Umbraco online,I just can't find the Mysterious File!
Where is it going!?
I need find the file to change text...

I try to search keyword like :Umbraco layout but can't find right answer for me... if you know what happen and what is the answer, please tell me, I can't thank you enough!

Answer (score 0):

Every project is individual. But commonly developers store layout pages in the "Partial" folder.

Answer (score 0):

The Layout/Master.cshtml file might not be created through Umbraco, but might be created through e.g. Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code, meaning Umbraco isn't aware that it exists.

To edit it, you would then have to edit the file directly through FTP, using an editor such as Visual Studio Code or similar.